# SDL_ttf surface to OpenGL texture channels mismatch

Tags: c, opengl, colors, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I trying to make OpenGL texture from SDL_ttf surface for score GUI in my game:

```
SDL_Color scoreColor = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };
SDL_Surface *score = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, "0 : 0", scoreColor);
SDL_Surface *scoreScaled = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 512, 512, 32, 0xff000000, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff);
SDL_Rect scoreRect = { 0, 0, score->w, score->h };
SDL_Rect scoreScaledRect = { 0, 0, scoreScaled->w, scoreScaled->h };
SDL_BlitScaled(score, &scoreRect, scoreScaled, &scoreScaledRect);
glGenTextures(1, &scoreTextureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, scoreTextureId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, scoreScaled->w, scoreScaled->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, scoreScaled->pixels);
SDL_FreeSurface(scoreScaled);
SDL_FreeSurface(score);
```

But it looks like red and alpha channel mismatch:
[image: screenshot]

I was trying to use GL_BGRA and GL_ABGR_EXT instead of GL_RGBA, but it only get another channels mismatch.

Comment: Anything change if you put a `glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)` after the `glBindTexture()`?

Comment: @genpfault It's make background white, text color not changed.